# How to put the space character into an element of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, character, space

I'm currently doing a program where I have to encrypt a string typed in by the user.
I can randomise the letters and let a = c (randomly generated letter) etc... but the one thing I can't seem to do is if there's a space in the string given by the user.
So if the user types in "Encrypt this string" , I will be given an error.
How can I put the space character in my array so I can change it when it is entered?

```
    char [] arrayAlphabet;
    arrayAlphabet = new char [26];
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        arrayAlphabet[i] = (char)('a' + i);
    }


   public static char [] createCipher(char [] arrayAlphabet, char [] cipherAlphabet)
{
    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(26);
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    {
        chars.add(c);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(chars);

    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++)
    {
        cipherAlphabet[i] = chars.get(i);
    }
    return cipherAlphabet;
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a for loop with `c = 'a'` and `c <= 'z'`, why not use `String`'s `toCharArray()` instead:

```
public static char[] createCipher() { // You weren't using your parameters, so I removed them. You can add them back if you want
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnpoqrstuvwxyz ".toCharArray(); // Add more characters to this string if you need them
    return shuffleArray(chars);
}

public static char[] shuffleArray(char[] array) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        char temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

(you'll also need to import `java.util.Random` for this to work)

What the `"...".toCharArray()` does is it takes the string with the characters you want, and, well turns them into a `char` array ;). The `shuffleArray()` is a general implementation of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) specifically for `char[]`, which is probably going to be faster than converting `char[]` to `List<Character>` and back again. (implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/837703)

(Note that character-swapping is ***not*** a good encryption in general, if you actually want to protect some information. It is a good exercise though.)

Comment: It says ArrayUtils cannot be resolved, I've imported arrays, lists, arraylists and collections though.

Comment: really appreciate the time and help

Comment: hey it's actually still not working for me unfortunately.
There's an error on the
    listCipher = new List<Character>(chars.length);
bit which leads to errors on the rest of the code

The error is :

Cannot instantiate the type List<Character>
and 
listCipher cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @MichaelVu That's odd. Everything compiled fine for me. I updated the answer again. Hopefully it will work this time.

Comment: "listChars cannot be resolved to a variable"
For some reason it just doesn't work

Comment: Sorry about all that. Could you try again just one more time please :)

Comment: Don't apologize haha, you're trying to help me so all I can do is thank you! And there's still an error unfrotunately

"The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<Character> is not applicable for the arguments (char[])"

Comment: @MichaelVu Okay :). I wrote the original in my IDE and then I changed a lot of stuff and I guess I didn't proof-read well enough, causing all the errors to creep in. Anyways I updated my answer and added a faster shuffle.

Comment: Finally :D Glad to have helped.